# Running bash/python script with ProcessBuilder

Tags: python, bash, xtext, xtend

I want to run a bash script by using ProcessBuilder. This is my xtend code:

```
new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("/bin/bash", "-c", "./myscript.sh")
```

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python WebRoot/result.py
```

And the python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
...
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WebRoot/result.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rospy
ImportError: No module named rospy
```

However, when I run the code manually via terminal, it works fine.

Comment: Maybe you need to do it like this: import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('your_package_name'). As per here: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Troubleshooting

Comment: And where does this 'import roslib...'  go?

Comment: Maybe you're not running the two from the same terminal? Check if you have e.g. PYTHONPATH set in one context but not the other, or if one references a different Python install

Comment: I am running it via Eclipse. Can be that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you run it command line, you are probably getting a different environment from when it's running in your JVM. In your bash script, try pointing directly to the python version you intend to use. It's entirely possible that the JVM's env is pointing to a different version of python. Or that the environment is not fully setup.

Try to put the full path, like this, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python2.7/python WebRoot/result.py
```